# Testing web api controller with ActionResult

Tags: c#, .net, unit-testing

I try to get result of GetAll() function in unit test, but i can't convert this to list. How can i do it correctly ?

Test:

```
    [Fact]
    public async Task GetAllHeroes_ShouldReturnAllHeroes()
    {
        var controller = new HeroesController(_heroes);

        var response = await controller.GetHeroes() as List<Hero>;
        //here i need response list, but there's error
    }
```

Controller:

```
    // GET: api/v1/heroes
    [HttpGet]
    [Produces(typeof(List<Hero>))]
    public async Task<ActionResult<IEnumerable<Hero>>> GetHeroes()
    {
        var result = await _heroes.GetAll();
        return Ok(result);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to parse the response to a list of your model

like this

```cs
var response = await controller.GetHeroes();

Assert.IsType<OkObjectResult>(result);

var content = ((OkObjectResult)result).Value;
Assert.IsType<List<Hero>>(content);

var Heros = (List<Hero>)content;
```

I added some other asserts that may be useful

Answer (score 0):

Does something like this work:

```
 // Act
var result = await controller.GetHeroes();
var response = result as OkNegotiatedContentResult<IEnumerable<Hero>>;

// Assert
// Assert.IsNotNull(response);
var heroes = response.Content.Result;
Assert.IsInstanceOfType(heroes, typeof(IEnumerable<Hero>), "Incorrect Types");

var dtos = heroes.ToArray();
// Asserting output
Assert.AreEqual(1, dtos.Length);
Assert.AreEqual(expected[0].id, dtos[0].id);
```

Comment: When i try cast, I have error: _Cannot cast „Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ActionResult<System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<api_dotnet.Models.Hero>>” to „System.Web.Http.Results.OkNegotiatedContentResult<System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<api_dotnet.Models.Hero>>”_

Comment: Is it MVC controller or API controller?

Comment: it's API controller

Answer (score 0):

For get IEnumerable, that is return to Action:

```
var response = await controller.GetHeroes();
var heroList = (IEnumerable<Hero>)response.Result;
```

More info [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/controllers/testing?view=aspnetcore-3.1)